# Best practice for custom input fields in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, input

I would like to style my input fields in ember.js like this:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/08/inspiration-text-input-effects/

It is not just the input field, but is accompanied also by:

- additional span and label tags for every input field and
- a general small custom js section that is taking care for visual effects

---

```
<span class="input input--haruki">
        <input class="input__field input__field--haruki" type="text" id="input-1" />
    <label class="input__label input__label--haruki" for="input-1">
        <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--haruki">First Name</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

---

What is a good way to wrap this for a convenient re-use?
Do you recommend putting this into an ember component?

Thank you,
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start might be implementing a component as follows:

```
App.CoolTextfieldComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ["input", "input--haruki"],
  idValue: null, 
  label: null
});
```

Component template as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/cool-textfield">

  {{ input type="text" id=idValue class="input__field input__field--haruki" value=value}}

  <label class="input__label input__label--haruki" {{ bind-attr for=idValue }}>
    <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--haruki">{{ label }}</span>
  </label>

</script>
```

This can then be used in your templates as follows:

`{{ cool-textfield idValue="input-1" label="First Name" value=name}}`

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gowami/1/edit?html,js,output)